# How format date to string in network request

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-volley

how save my date in Mysql DB, below the code i use, where save location, and repeat x time.

But now i need save date, i try like i show in the code fragment.

This is update my code.

```
public void startGeo(View view) {
    isRunning = true;
    ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertURL, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("latitude", t_latitude.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("longitude", t_longitude.getText().toString());


                    return parameters;

                }
                protected void sendLocationDataToWebsite(Location location) {
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                    Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("date", URLEncoder.encode(dateFormat.format(date), "UTF-8");

                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Enviado", LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (isRunning) {
                ha.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

Very thnks

Comment: The code you have shared doesn't have anything database related. What did you try so far?

Comment: yes, the BD is related, only i need to know how save date in it.

Comment: i update the code

Comment: Still just looks like a HTTP request/response handler. Really unclear where the database access would be required and whether you have tried anything in this respect so far.

Comment: Yes, it already saves my location in the BD. now what I need only, is to save the date, i dont know as I establish the code, i try as shown in the lower part

Answer (score 1):

This is code for date

```
private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

And this code for put in request

```
parameters.put("date", getDateTime());
```